# React: Define constants?

Tags: reactjs

I have a container component which is feeding a presentation component with one image at a time (every time a user clicks a button). I want to define those image paths in a constant (array). But I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined` when trying to read from that array.

How can I solve that error, and is this the best approach?

```
export default class ImageContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentImage: '/images/dummy-image-1.jpg'
    }

    this.changeImage = this.changeImage.bind(this)

    const images = [
      '/images/dummy-image-1.jpg',
      '/images/dummy-image-2.jpg',
      '/images/dummy-image-3.jpg',
      '/images/dummy-image-4.jpg',
      '/images/dummy-image-5.jpg'
    ]
  }

  changeImage(event){
    console.log(this.images[1])
    //Do something
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ImageView image={this.state.currentImage} changeImage={this.changeImage} />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define `images` as object property in constructor:

```
this.images = [
  '/images/dummy-image-1.jpg',
  ...
];
```

when you declare variables (using `var`, `let`, `const`) it is visible only in function (in your case constructor) scope.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Btw: Is it a good approach to do it this way (making an array in the constructor, and use that array later in the component)?

Comment: @allegutta Sure, it is completely legal to define object properties in constructor and I would say constructor is the best place for it.

Answer (score 7):

You could move the const definition outside of the class:

```
const images = [
  '/images/dummy-image-1.jpg',
  '/images/dummy-image-2.jpg',
  '/images/dummy-image-3.jpg',
  '/images/dummy-image-4.jpg',
  '/images/dummy-image-5.jpg'
];

export default class ImageContainer extends Component {
    //...
}
```

This way `images` remains a `const` and it's still only visible to the code within the file (which I'll assume is just the `ImageContainer` class).

Comment: Nice approach. Didn't know it was only visible to the code within the file when it is placed outside the component. Thank you.

Comment: Same here, it really helps a lot to understand constants and imports outside components.